# NSCoding : Found nil unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nscoding

since updating to Swift 3 I get this very known crash that I'm not able to solve by myself... :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* :

on line

`self.isDefault = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoxUserDefault_isDefault") as! Bool`

Why would it crash now ?

Here's my class

```
class BoxUserDefault: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var frendlyName: String
    var hostname: String
    var isDefault: Bool

    init(frendlyName: String, hostname: String, isDefault: Bool) {
        self.frendlyName = frendlyName
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.isDefault = isDefault
        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.frendlyName, forKey: "BoxUserDefault_frendlyName")
        aCoder.encode(self.hostname, forKey: "BoxUserDefault_hostname")
        aCoder.encode(self.isDefault, forKey: "BoxUserDefault_isDefault")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.frendlyName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoxUserDefault_frendlyName") as! String
        self.hostname = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoxUserDefault_hostname") as! String
        self.isDefault = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoxUserDefault_isDefault") as! Bool

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Any idea ? thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the appropriate method `decodeBool(forKey:`

```
self.isDefault = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "BoxUserDefault_isDefault")!
```

Comment: Looks like it's working fine ! Feeling stupid ^^ Thanks mate